# Date format changes when I call onselect event of bootstrap date picker

Tags: jquery, date-format, bootstrap-datepicker

I used Bootstrap date picker with  `data-date-format="mm/yyyy"` 
Here is my HTML code for date picker.

```
<div class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm/yyyy"  data-provide="datepicker">
  <input id="acafimon" name="nperfimon" type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This Displayed only Months and Years in date picker when I select it.
 
Now I used `datepicker()` function and called `onSelect` event with jQuery 
Here is that code

```
$("#acafimon").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        alert("Date Selected");
    }
});
```

It changed the date format `mm/yyyy` to `mm/dd/yyyy` format and included date when displaying.
What is way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/yyyy' }).val();
```

to change date format

Comment: Your answer is not concerned with the event onSelect  of date picker.